# Using EntityFramework.Extensions library with LOB project

Tags: c#, entity-framework

EntityFramework.Extensions library used to update entities as following

```
//update all tasks with status of 1 to status of 2
context.Tasks.Update(
        t => t.StatusId == 1,
        t2 => new Task {StatusId = 2});
```

In LOB application if user modifies multiple properties of collection of entities in user interface then they are sent to the Service layer to be updated, the above syntax is not practical
how this batch of entities with different properties for different entities changed could be updated using EntityFramework.Extensions

For Example when using Generic Repository for same purpose:

```
 public virtual void Update(params T[] items)
    {
       using (var context = new Entities())
        {
          foreach (T item in items)
          {
             context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
          }
         context.SaveChanges();
       }
    }
```

How can we do the same using EntityFramework.Extensions library

Answer (score 0):

There are unfortunately two Entity Framework Extensions Library.

The first library is in Beta since 2012 and unsupported by the owner: https://entityframeworkext.codeplex.com/

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

The second library support all kind of bulk operations:

- BulkSaveChanges
- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge
- And more.

You can easily bulk update multiples entities with different value using this library:

```
public virtual void Update(params T[] items)
{
   using (var context = new Entities())
   {
       context.BulkUpdate(items);
   }
}
```